# How do I parse this HTML using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

Based on this HTML:

```
<li><strong><a href="http://www.ukasta.org.uk/">United Kingdom Agricultural Supply Trade Association</a> (UKASTA)</strong></li>
```

I want to get the `United Kingdom Agricultural Supply TradeAssociation` and `(UKASTA)` strings.

Using Nokogiri, I wrote:

```
linklist=link.parent.parent.css('li strong a')
linklist.each do |f|
  puts f.text
end
```

`f.text` is "United Kingdom Agricultural Supply TradeAssociation",
but how do I get "(UKASTA)"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're diving in too deep. I'd use:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '<li><strong><a href="http://www.ukasta.org.uk/">United Kingdom Agricultural Supply Trade Association</a> (UKASTA)</strong></li>'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.at('strong').text
```

Which returns:

```
"United Kingdom Agricultural Supply Trade Association (UKASTA)"
```

If you have to find the `<a>` node, you can access "(UKASTA)" using:

```
a_node = doc.at('a')
a_node.text
=> "United Kingdom Agricultural Supply Trade Association"
a_node.next_sibling.text
=> " (UKASTA)"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `children` method, and then identify the data by position:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<html><li><strong><a href="">United Kingdom Agricultural Supply Trade Association</a>(UKASTA)</strong></li></html>")

html_doc.css('li strong').children[0].text
=> United Kingdom Agricultural Supply Trade Association
html_doc.css('li strong').children[1]
=> (UKASTA)
```

Comment: Note that if you want it combined as a single string, you can also do `html_doc.css('li strong').text` to get `United Kingdom Agricultural Supply Trade Association (UKASTA)`

Comment: `.css('li strong').children[0]` is an awkward way to get to the node you want. `css` returns a NodeSet, which is akin to an Array. Then you're saying `children`, which would be another array, then `[0]` to get the first element. Instead, use `at` instead of `css`. It returns the first occurrence of the accessor as a Node, so it short-circuits `.css('li strong').children[0]` nicely.